# Highlight reference in Visual Studio 2012 JavaScript (nodejs)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-2012, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to get the functionality (in any way) of highlighting all references of the 'selected' variable in nodejs (I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Premium with Node.js Tools 1.0 RC)? The very same functionality already exists for the C#, but for the unknown reasons to me, it's not possible for Node.js/JavaScript.

I've searched web a little, and found solutions like Accent Occurrences extension, but to make it work I have to select the whole variable name (double click) - but what I desire is to trigger highlighting action just when I place the cursor onto the variable (single click).

Thanks in advance for any help.